# Extract value from location hash

Tags: javascript, web, url

In the front-end Javascript code, I need to extract a value from the location hash parameter.
For example, the url looks like:

```
https://mywebsite.com/certainpage#comment-12345
```

Here, I want to extract the value `12345` which indicates the id of comment. Currently, I am using the following code to do it:

```
const match = window.location.hash.match(/-([0-9]*)/) || [];

if (!match[1]) return;

// Use match[1]
```

If there is any optimized and clean way to handle this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always `#comment-NUM`, then you don't even need to go for RegEx.

```
const match = window.location.hash.split("-") || [];
```

Then the same checks will apply. Use `match[1]` going forward. The reason is, [`String.split` is better in performance than `String.match`](https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/7822/0/strmatch-vs-strsplit). Also, it looks lot cleaner too.

Comment: I added my own test case with your case too: https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/10308/0/split-vs-match